# Error: while running the Model Optimizer on the pretrained Caffe* model in Intel OpenVINO

Tags: caffe, openvino

while running the Model Optimizer on the pretrained Caffe* model in Intel OpenVINO
The "/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/downloader/public/mobilenet-ssd/mobilenet-ssd.caffemodel" is not existing file

Answer (score 1):

Message clearly states that model is not present. You need to download it.

- Clone [this](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo) OpenVINO modelzoo.
- Go to tools/downloader.
- Install the dependencies.

`python3 -mpip install --user -r ./requirements.in`

- Download `mobilenet-ssd` model to the desired path.

`./downloader.py --name mobilenet-ssd --output_dir /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/open_model_zoo/tools/downloader/public/mobilenet-ssd/`

Note: It downloads the model using [these](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/public/mobilenet-ssd) files. Refer [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/deploying-ai-at-the-edge-with-intel-openvino-part-1-51a09752fb4e) for details.